# MonoTouch 'could not AOT the assembly'

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm using MonoTouch 6.2 and I have an app that builds and runs fine on the simulator, but gets a "Could not AOT the assembly" error when I build for the actual device.

Has anyone seen this before?

Here's the compiler output:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++  -miphoneos-version-min=4.3 -arch armv7  -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -x assembler-with-cpp -c /var/folders/rw/m66cxvf16kq37jjxdt0d99580000gn/T/tmpc3662b4.tmp/GoogleAnalytics.dll.armv7.s -o /var/folders/rw/m66cxvf16kq37jjxdt0d99580000gn/T/tmpc3662b4.tmp/GoogleAnalytics.dll.armv7.o
AOT Compilation exited with code 134, command:
MONO_PATH=/Users/me/dev/MyApp/Src/Plat/iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/MyApp.app /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --debug --aot=mtriple=armv7-darwin,full,static,asmonly,direct-icalls,soft-debug,no-direct-calls,iphone-abi,outfile=/var/folders/rw/m66cxvf16kq37jjxdt0d99580000gn/T/tmpc3662b4.tmp/MyApp.exe.armv7.s "/Users/me/dev/MyApp/Src/Plat/iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/MyApp.app/MyApp.exe"
Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly /Users/me/dev/MyApp/Src/Plat/iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/MyApp.app/MyApp.exe
* Assertion at ../../../../../mono/mono/metadata/marshal.c:8613, condition `sig->param_count == invoke_sig->param_count + 1' not met


Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly /Users/me/dev/MyApp/Src/Plat/iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/MyApp.app/mscorlib.dll
Code: 1337720 Info: 35037 Ex Info: 487954 Unwind Info: 8707 Class Info: 22674 PLT: 3057 GOT Info: 65112 GOT: 22092 Offsets: 31427
Output file: '/var/folders/rw/m66cxvf16kq37jjxdt0d99580000gn/T/tmpc3662b4.tmp/mscorlib.dll.armv7.s'.
Linking symbol: '_mono_aot_module_mscorlib_info'.
Compiled 6288 out of 6288 methods (100%)
Methods without GOT slots: 4052 (64%)
Direct calls: 246 (2%)
JIT time: 1134 ms, Generation time: 1793 ms, Assembly+Link time: 203 ms.

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++  -miphoneos-version-min=4.3 -arch armv7  -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -x assembler-with-cpp -c /var/folders/rw/m66cxvf16kq37jjxdt0d99580000gn/T/tmpc3662b4.tmp/mscorlib.dll.armv7.s -o /var/folders/rw/m66cxvf16kq37jjxdt0d99580000gn/T/tmpc3662b4.tmp/mscorlib.dll.armv7.o
error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly '/Users/me/dev/MyApp/Src/Plat/iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/MyApp.app/MyApp.exe'
  at MTouch.GetObjectFileForAssembly (System.String assemblyName, Abi abi) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MTouch+<CompileAssemblies>c__AnonStorey10.<>m__1A (System.String s) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel+<ForEach>c__AnonStorey36`1[System.String].<>m__34 (System.String e, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState s, System.Object l) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel+<ForEach>c__AnonStorey35`2[System.String,System.Object].<>m__32 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskActionInvoker+ActionInvoke.Invoke (System.Threading.Tasks.Task owner, System.Object state, System.Threading.Tasks.Task context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThreadStart () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.. the problem was I had a MonoPInvokeCallbackAttribute with a delegate type that didn't match the signature of the function. For example:

```
delegate int SomeDelegate();

[ MonoPInvokeCallbackAttribute ( typeof( SomeDelegate ) ) ]
static void MyCallback( int x )
{
}
```

So the signature of **SomeDelegate** doesn't match the signature of **MyCallback**.

Comment: What might make this answer useful is if you share how you learned that this was the problem.