# Resolving Xamarin AOT Errors

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am getting the following when deploying from Windows to an iOS device:

> Could not AOT the assembly
>   '/Users/buildserver/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Investor.iOS/d99017eb03395769b8f7f4a145086854/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/64/3-Build/TPService.dll'  Investor.iOS    C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets

My question is two-fold:

**What causes this issue and how do I resolve it?**

My project settings are as follows:

[image]

Comment: In [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286404/monotouch-could-not-aot-the-assembly) question, it seemed to be an issue with some function signature... Would it be the case here as well?

Comment: See if you hit a limitation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/internals/limitations